# vim count number of lines not containing a pattern

Tags: vim

Given a CSV file below, how can i use vim to count the number of lines that do not contain: `fff` or `sss`

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee, 3221
aaa ddd eee fff, 3222
fff ddd sss www aaa, 3223
ggg www qqq, 3224
sss aaa vvv, 3225
```

I have this but it only matches some and not all

```
%s/\v^(fff|sss)//gn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` anchors in the start of the line, so it match **lines starting with fff or sss**. It is a sort of negative only when inside square brackets (`[^a]` matches anything except `a`).

You are looking for something like this:

```
%s/\v^((fff|sss)@!.)*$//gn
```

More info at `:help @!`.

Another solution, which avoids the complex regex, is to use the global command to increment a variable on all lines that does NOT match the pattern:

```
let var=0
v/\v(sss|fff)/let var+=1
echo var
```

**Edit:**

---

You can delete all lines by using the following global command:

```
g/\v(sss|fff)/d
```

Comment: thanks, could you also help with if i want to delete all lines containing fff or sss does this work: `v/\v^((fff|sss)@!.)*$/d`

Comment: does `g!/\v(sss|fff)/d` do the same to delete all lines containing the above?

Comment: `:g!` and `:v` are the same.  See `:help :v`

Comment: yes so i was interested to know if @mMontu answer of `g/\v(sss|fff)/d` was equivalent to `g!/\v(sss|fff)/d`

Comment: `:g` and `:g!` are complements.  The first will delete all lines containing "sss" or "fff".  The second will delete all lines *not* containing these strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke the powers of the command line from vim with %. So type in the following and press enter. It will take you outside vim to give you the answer. Press enter again and you are back in vim exactly as before.

```
:%!grep -c -v -P "fff|sss"
```